# Tableau data extract refresh

Tags: refresh, extract, tableau-api

So I have this database which I will build a dashboard with. A tableau admin will refresh d extract everyday.

example of data
Date     item
1-jul.       Book
2-jul.       Cane
.
.
24-jul      Rice
25-jul.     Car

Everyday new row is added

Question: how do I set up my date range filters in d data source view so that the extract refreshes by the admin will reflect the current data always.

Answer (score 0):

One solution although bit long is:

Create calculated field "date2" as type date (based on date info from your data.) use date function if e.g year id missing.

Create calculated field "max date" as type date (max(date2))

then create yet another calculated field "max date filter"
If date2 = [max date] then 1 end

Drag filter field to filters and set it to 1
Drag item to rows

Comment: Thank you. But I mean extract filters. Filters to create the extract. How do I setup the data extract to always refresh to current data